# formik submiting set values into formvalue

Tags: reactjs, formik

Need help pulling data in to formik formvalue

```
                          <Field 
                                        value={group.name}
                                        name="oldgroup"
                                        type="hidden"                                     
                                      />
```

Seems formik wont submit the set value to my formvalue.....
without formik i might use e.target.value to get the value into a formvalue object.
but i couldnt figure that out with formik.

how do i pull set values into my formvalue when i submit?

```
 {groups.user.map((group => {
            return (
            <div style={{width:554, height:100}}className="userlist" key={group._id}>
                    <label>name:<p>{group.name}</p></label>
                          
                 <div style={{display:"flex"}}>
                    <div>
                        <Formik
                            initialValues={initialValues2}
                            validationSchema={validationSchema}
                            validateOnChange={false}
                            validateOnBlur={false}
                            onSubmit={handleRenameGroup}>
                                {({ errors, touched,  setErrors}) => (
                        <Form >
                                <div>
                                <button type="submit" disabled={loading}>
                                    {loading && (
                                    <span className="spinner-border spinner-border-sm"></span>
                                        )}
                                        <span>Add Group</span></button>
                                        <Field onClick={e => {
                                            setErrors({errors: {}})
                                        }}
                                        placeholder="Enter new group here"
                                        name="group"
                                        type="text"
                                        className={ 
                                            (errors.group && touched.group    
                                            ? " is-invalid"
                                            : "")
                                        }/>
                                        <ErrorMessage
                                        name="group"
                                        component="div"
                                        className="invalid-feedback"/>
                                        <Field 
                                        value={group.name}
                                        name="oldgroup"
                                        type="hidden"                                     
                                      />
                                     
                                </div>
                        </Form>
                                )}    
                        </Formik> 
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <button onClick={handleRemoveGroup} value={group.name}>Remove</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            )
            }))}
```

end result should be formvalue = {group:value, oldgroup:value}

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I solved it by using setFieldValue..

```
 onClick={e => {
 setFieldValue("oldgroup", group.name)
```

by using this on the field i did want to interact with, it set the hidden fields value and was successfully submitted to the formvalue object on submit.